# What construction is the Velbon PH-159Q Head?

Tags: tripod-heads

Metal or Plastic?

Answer (score 2):

Plastic.

According to [this table](http://www.velbon.co.uk/newvelbon/pages/quickrel.html) the PH-159Q head is used among other on the CX-560 tripod. You can find some information for example [here](http://www.digitalcamerawarehouse.com.au/prod3391.htm), where it says that major components is made out of plastic.

There are some pretty good pictures in [this review](http://www.thephotoforum.com/forum/photography-equipment-products-news-reviews/107308-velbon-cx-560-tripod-review.html).

Comment: Seems the "made out plastic" applies to the tripod, in that link, not the head. BUT the photos...

Comment: @sebastien.b: As the head is non-removable, I think that it is meant to apply to the head also.

Answer (score 1):

You would think Googling or looking up Velbon.co.uk would help, but not so much. The closest I could get was the specs of the PH-157Q, which is likely to be similar, and "All die-cast metal construction".
http://www.velbon.co.uk/newvelbon/pages/proheads.html

Comment: The PH-159Q is a non-removalbe head used on the inexpensive range of tripods, so it's actually very different from the pro-series PH-157Q, despite the similarities in the name.